# Symfony truncated errors annoyingly cut off my error messag (truncated...)

Tags: php, symfony, truncated

While the error I have is also a question in itself, my particular current issue is that I can't even read half the error because it's truncated,
so I have no clue what the error actually **is**.

*terminal*

```
$ vendor/bin/behat features/album.feature
Feature: Provide a consistent standard JSON API endpoint

In order to build interchangeable front ends
  As a JSON API developer
  I need to allow Create, Read, Update, and Delete functionality

  Background:                                          # features\album.feature:7
    Given there are Albums with the following details: # FeatureContext::thereAreAlbumsWithTheFollowingDetails()
      | title                     | track_count | release_date              |
      | The Dark side of the Moon | 12          | 1973-03-24T00:00:00+00:00 |
      | Back in Black             | 9           | 1980-06-25T23:22:21+00:00 |
      | Thriller                  | 23          | 1982-11-30T11:10:09+00:00 |
      Server error: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/album` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
      {
          "code": 500,
          "message": "Unexpected error occured: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Album (t (truncated...)
       (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException)
```

The error is apparently given by my Exception Controller.

*ExceptionController.php*

```
...
/**
 * @Rest\View()
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $exception
 * @param DebuggerLoggerInterface|null $logger
 * @return View
 */
public function show(Request $request, $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null){
    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        return $this->getView($exception->getStatusCode(), json_decode($exception->getMessage(), true));
    }

    if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
        return $this->getView($exception->getStatusCode(), $exception->getMessage());
    }

    return $this->getView(null, 'Unexpected error occured: '.$exception->getMessage());
}
...
```

How do I lose the truncation and see the full error?

Comment: by checking the log files

Comment: So `./var/log/dev.log` is the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the logs files:

```
var/log/dev.log
```

You could also do something like

```
tail -f var/log/dev.log
```

To see what follow what is getting written in your logs

Answer (score 6):

You can go to 
vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php Line 139.

And change this line : $summary = $body->read(120);
You should be able to read more than 120 bytes and get a better idea about the error you're getting. (for debugging only)

Comment: Add in the other answer `./var/log/dev.log` and I'll accept it.

Comment: In my case the file didn't exist to find the good one you could just grep -R ./vendor/{GuzzleRepository} "(truncated...)"

Comment: @AlexandreCorvino `rgrep "(truncated...)" vendor/*guzzle*` (beware args order)